# How can i send mail from a specific/fixed email address using gmail api?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

My chrome extension have a button. When user click this button, some data will be parsed and sent to user defined email address as csv attachment. The sender mail will be fixed (my email).

How can i do this? Is there any way I can do this using Gmail API?

Comment: The user would have to log in with your Google credentials in order to allow the extension to send email from your account. The alternative is to set up a server and have the extension send the info to the server so it can in turn send out the email.

Comment: Kindly provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).